# Module augmentation on same interface, multiple modules

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend an interface from a module, multiple times.
Lets sum up some of the definitions:

- An interface I want to extend, lets call it `Metadata`
- Main package that creates the interface, lets call it `main-package`
- Module A that extends the `Metadata` interface, lets call it `module-A`
- Module B that also extends the `Metadata` interface, lets call it `module-B`

---

In the `main-package`, I have the following interface:

```
export interface Metadata {
  name: string;
}
```

I want to extend this `Metadata` in Module A, like so:

```
import 'main-package';

declare module 'main-package' {
  interface Metadata {
    location: string;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly, and now I can access the keys `name` & `location`, when Module A is installed.

---

Next, I have Module B, which also wants to extend the `Metadata`, like so:

```
import 'main-package';

declare module 'main-package' {
  interface Metadata {
    notes: string;
  }
}
```

In the package itself, this works perfect. I can access the keys `name` & `notes`.

---

Now I install `main-package`, `module-A` and `module-B` into one project. When I access the `Metadata` interface, I can only access `name` & `location`. The key `notes` from `module-B` is completely ignored.

Some thoughts:

- I've tried to import `Metadata` only from 'main-package', didn't make a difference;
- All `declare module` files are separate files;
- The files are built from `.ts` into `.d.ts` files and the above snippets are the results.

I've been searching everywhere, but couldn't find the answer for my problem. It's been hours, but no progress yet.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution for my problem. I would be forever thankful!

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a web IDE project like stackblitz or codesandbox and provide a link?  If you make it easier for others to demo the issue for themselves then you make it more likely you'll get an applicable answer.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Solved it by rewriting the source interface as you described here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46617